# How to change apps default language on Debian?

Tags: debian, arm

I have an arm-based computer(nanopi) that is Chinese, so the default language of iceweasle is Chinese(it shows the results of search by google's Chinese engine) how can I fix that and remove Chinese language and set English to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check available locale run `locale -a` , to change the locale e,g: ENG , add the following line to your `~./bashrc`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then run:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

And select `US.UTF-8`

**edit**

Iceweasel is deprecated , you should use firefox : `apt-get install firefox-esr`

Then you can change the language from `about:preferences#content`

Comment: I did it but still the buttons mark is in Chinese language! I mean for example instead of "Search" it's written something Chinese on the button in google.com page

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen
echo 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' > /etc/deault/locale
```